# Como integro un lector de QR a mi sitio web?

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio en el cual validare cupones en codigo QR, como integro una app externa que abra en mi sitio para que pueda leer el QR?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es de suponer que el usuario visitante a tu web ya debe tener un lector de QR instalado en su dispositivo, aunque claro que solo podrá leer el QR que se muestre en otra pantalla, pero si buscas integrar uno a tu sitio para arrastrar un QR en formato de imagen, mira **[AQUÍ](https://webqr.com/)**.
---------

Comment: Asi es, previaente tendra un lector instalado, pero como puedo hacer para que abra el letor, el sitio es nativo

Comment: No te complique (obligas al usuario a tener un QR Ready instalado, algo que no es positivo), y mejor mira el link que te dejé en el primer comentario. Ahí está lo que necesitas.

Comment: Sale, muchas gracias!

Comment: OK. Vota la respuesta, porfa.